# How to inculde one group of optional-dependencies in another?

Tags: python, pyproject.toml

If I have 2 groups of `project.optional-dependencies` in my `pyproject.toml`, is there a way to specify that installing one group installs the dependencies of the other?

E.g.

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest",
    "pytest-asyncio",
    "pytest-cov",
]

dev = [
    "flake8",
    "flake8-import-order",
    "black",
]
```

How can I specify that installing `myproj[dev]` also installs `[test]`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure from which pip version this is possible, on `22.2.2` it is, on `20.0.2` it isn't.

```
[project]
name = "my-pkg"


[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest",
    "pytest-asyncio",
    "pytest-cov",
]

dev = [
    "flake8",
    "flake8-import-order",
    "black",
    "my-pkg[test]"
]
```

source => https://hynek.me/articles/python-recursive-optional-dependencies/